# Setting up directories for CRON job using Linux bash shell to collect data using an R script

Tags: r, linux, windows, bash, cron

I am having trouble to set up a CRON job using my Linux bash shell as a subsystem of Windows 10. The idea is to collect data from Twitter using a simple R script.

First, I setup a job in the crontab. I have tried several ways to write the directory where I have my Rscript and where I want to save my tweets. Here some examples:

```
* * * * 7  /mnt/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/Twitter/collect.R
* * * * 7  cd /mnt/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/Twitter; Rscript collect.R
```

In the R script, the first line of code that I use is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

Then the R script contains several lines that I use to collect to collect tweets (this piece of code works well).

After that I use a piece of code to store my tweets:

```
# Specify dir (I have tried several ways to write this)
dirPath <- "C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\Twitter"

# Create dir for storage
if(!dir.exists(paste0(dirPath, "tweets/"))){
  dir.create("tweets/")
}

# Write csv with date
save_as_csv(newTweets, paste0(dirPath, "tweets/", Sys.Date(), ".csv"),
            prepend_ids = TRUE, na = "",
            fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

That's all. I have been trying to use this for a couple of days and no folder called "tweets" shows up containing the collected tweets.

I have checked and CRON is properly initialise:

```
~$ service cron status 
* cron is running
```

**Edition 25/05/2020**

1. As suggested by one of the users, the problem might be related with the shebang, so I quoted spaces in the folders name. This didn't work.
2. I also thought that the problem might be that R had not been exported to the linux PATHS so I added the environment to `/usr/bin/env`. Now Rscript is reachable from two different paths there. Now, I changed the shebang of my Rscript:

   `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript`
3. I have tested whether the script is running when I execute it manually. This is the result:

When I execute `/mnt/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/Twitter/collect.R` and the shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` the outcome in the shell is:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'Rscript': No such file or directory
```

If I type `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript.exe` as a shebang instead. I obtain:

`Fatal error: cannot open file /mnt/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/Twitter/collect.R: Permission denied`

Considering this, I have proceded to do `sudo visudo` and then add the line 
`mysuername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /mnt/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/Twitter` below #User privilege specification. Saved changes.

The error persists.

**Edition 2**

1. Checking filesystem: command `df -h`

[image]

I much appreciate your help!

Comment: Cheers @alecxs. I am also trying this `#!/mnt/c/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/bin Rscript` and doesn't seem to work. I am missing something

Comment: @pyring could you please provide us with scheduling dates?

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Odeh Sure, I am using right now `58 17 * * 7` to test it. (UK time, which is also my computer time according to my shell.

Comment: @alecxs thanks, I have tried this and it doesnt seem to work either :(

Comment: Thanks @alecks. I have tried this. Unfortunately, the problem persists. I have edited the question with more info.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript.exe` seems to work. now `chmod a+x collect.R` and try again

Comment: Thanks again @alecxs. The problem persists after `chmod a+x /path/collect.R`. Permission denied. :(

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx  1  username username DATE  /mnt/c/Users/xxxx/collect.R `

Comment: I don't know much about system types and partitions, and I am pretty new in Linux. But I have added a screenshot to the question if it helps. As for other files, I can not open a simple script.sh

Comment: `C:\134 /mnt/c drvfs rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off 0 0`. Additionally, I have reinstalled R and I have exported the new paths to /usr/bin/env

Comment: There are several paths to Rscript.exe in /usr/bin/env. It seems that the permissions of the files of environment `"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/R-4.0.0/bin/x64"` are `-r-xr-xr-x 1`, while in `/mnt/c/Users/xxxx/R-4.0.0/bin/x64`  are `-rwxrwxrwx 1`. Also, when I try `chmod a+x "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/R-4.0.0/bin/x64/Rscript.exe"`, I get `chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/R-4.0.0/bin/x64/Rscript.exe': Permission denied`.

Comment: the r-x is sufficient for executing, mount flags are fine

Comment: That shebang #! gives me a bad interpreter: No such a file or directory. Apparently shebangs do not accept spaces. That's why I added the other path too... :)

Comment: i guess the Permission denied is because Rscript.exe is for windows only - do you have another Rscript binary without file extension (for linux)? unfortunately i never used R

Comment: mmmm Interesting @alecxs. Indeed, the R version I have is downloaded for windows. Should I install R for Linux? Never did this. Is it easy?

Comment: This was the issue @alecxs. Thank you for your help.